# Адрес рабочего стола

Tags: windows

Есть ли разница между `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop` и `%SYSTEMDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\Desktop\` в том плане что-бы путь был правильным на версиях Windows от Windows XP? Я где-то видел что на компьютере вообще 2 папки рабочего стола, одна `Desktop` а другая `Рабочий стол`. И они разные, одна пустая а другая нет. Это что значит? Как правильно указать путь к рабочему столу независимо от версии ОС и прочего?

Пока получаю путь `System.getenv("USERPROFILE")`. Получается `C:\Users\User`. Не знаю везде ли это будет работать.

Написал вот так, так как в Windows XP на котором я только что проверил папка называлась `Рабочий стол`

```
Path ADRESS = Paths.get(System.getenv("USERPROFILE") + "\\Desktop");

    if(Files.exists(ADRESS)) {
        \\
    }

ADRESS = Paths.get(System.getenv("USERPROFILE") + "\\Рабочий стол");

    if(Files.exists(ADRESS)) {            
        \\
    }
```

Comment: Второй вариант однозначно неверный, поскольку теоретически рабочий стол может располагаться не на системном диске.

Comment: @Yaant Да, понял

Comment: Рабочий стол может отсутствовать по обоим путям, проверено в Windows XP

Comment: @andreymal Можете объяснить тогда?

Comment: А я сам не знаю как правильно, я простой юзер, просто предупредил)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%USERPROFILE%\Desktop` - выведет на папку рабочего стола пользователя с вероятностью 90%, потому что домашние пользователи редко меняют настройки по-умолчанию и вообще догадываются об их существовании.

Значение системное переменной `%USERPROFILE%` содержит абсолютный путь (включает букву диска и все промежуточные папки) к папке профиля пользователя, и задается операционной системой (менять руками категорически не рекомендуется).

`%Public%\Desktop\` - выведет на общую папку рабочего стола для всех пользователей.

Название папки по-умолчанию всегда `Desktop`. Локализованное название задается с помощью настроек в скрытом файле `desktop.ini` и является просто синонимом.

Папка рабочего стола, как и почти все папки вроде `Documents`, `Favorites` и т.д. могут быть перенаправлены в произвольное место, включая сетевые ресурсы, с помощью групповых политик, либо ручной настройкой самим пользователем. В этом случае `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop` вернет неверный путь, и даже при наличии там соответствующей папки, пользователь не увидит на своем рабочем столе добавленные в нее файлы.

В таком случае, для получения текущего пути к рабочему столу пользователя, можно воспользоваться реестром.

Нам нужна ветка:
`"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders"`
и в ней ключ `Desktop`, значение которого содержит абсолютный путь к текущему рабочему столу пользователя. В этой же ветке можно найти и другие ключи, которые содержат пути к соответствующим папкам пользователя.

Информация по реестру верна для всех версий, начиная с Win2000 до Win10 включительно.

---

Полезные ссылки:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/6083.windows-xp-folders-and-locations-vs-windows-7-and-vista.aspx
http://libertyboy.free.fr/computing/reference/envariables/

Comment: Смотрел папки на Windows XP и там была только одна папка под названием Рабочий стол

Comment: @ELe удалите из нее desktop.ini и увидите ее настоящее название. вы же не думаете что для разных локализацй в MS стали бы делать отдельные структуры папок?

Comment: @ELe вообще, через desktop.ini любой папке можно дать произвольное имя не совпадающее с оригиналом. И у папки будет два имени, видимое и настоящее

Comment: И в пути к папке тоже будет произвольное имя? У меня в пути был Рабочий стол. Через консоль не смог найти Desktop. Переменная юзера содержала Рабочий стол

Comment: @ELe в пути в реестре, будет настоящее имя. А вообще указывать можно любое из этих имен: и настоящее, и синоним. Они в данном случае равнозначны

Comment: Нужно проверить реестр на Windows XP

Comment: @ELe согласно документации информация по реестру верна  начиная с Win2000 по текущую версию

Comment: @А будет ли в Windows XP не User Shell Folders а Shell Folders и в ней Desktop? У меня на Windows 10 там содержится полный путь до рабочего стола.

Comment: @ELe по идее да. В реестре некоторые ветки продублированы, в том смысле, что есть текущие активные ветки, и сохраненные пользователем, и сохраненные просто замещают текущие при входе пользователя, но это не для всех веток верно

Comment: @ELe в Shell Folders больше настроек чем в User Shell Folders, во всяком случае в win 7

Comment: @Мне нужно быть уверенным что там будет содержатся путь до рабочего стола пользователя независимо от версии Windows. Использую только его. Я так понимаю это настройки текущей учетной записи?

Comment: @ELe для версий от 2000 до 10, будет, для более ранних и последующих сами понимаете =)

Comment: @ELe К тому же лучший способ получить 100% гарантию - это проверить, а не верить на слово кому бы то ни было. Виртуалки еще ни кто не запрещал, поставьте да посмотрите.

Comment: Добро, уже качаю Microsoft Virtual PC

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/641624/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B2-windows-xp-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8 Помогите получить значение, \\s+ удаляет символы

Answer (score 1):

Современные версии windows пишут алиас к папке Desktop "Рабочий стол". Поэтому правильно было бы, как я считаю писать C:\Users\%USERPROFILE%\Desktop.

Comment: При указании пути нужно указывать диск C:\ ? То есть C:\%USERPROFILE%\Desktop ? Или нужно указать пути до папки с пользователями?

Comment: Да, конечно C:\%USERPROFILE%\Desktop

Comment: Без папки пользователей?(Users)

Comment: Нет с папкой пользователя C:\Users\%USERPROFILE%\Desktop

Comment: В комментариях написали что и 1 и 2 путь может быть неверным.

Comment: @Enlightener Не вводите в заблуждение. В `%USERPROFILE%` уже содержится и имя диска и Users. То есть `C:\Users\%USERPROFILE%\Desktop` будет эквивалентно `C:\Users\C:\Users\<имя пользователя>\Desktop`.

Comment: @Yaant Как быть?

Comment: @ELe насчет WinXP не скажу, уже не помню, как оно там было. Но на более старших версиях вариант `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop` должен работать.

Comment: @Yaant Очень жаль что не скажете